# How do i change a method with enhanced for-loop that returns a method call in to a Stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method called `getBalance` where I have an enhanced for loop and inside the loop I return `customer.getBalance();`

I now want to change that method in to a Stream from Java 8 and I can't figure out how to do it since you cannot return something inside a stream.

The method:

```
public double getBalance(String personalNumber, int accountNumber) {

    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        if (customer.getPersonalNumber().equals(personalNumber)) {
            return customer.getBalance(accountNumber);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `customers.stream().filter(customer->customer.getPersonalNumber().equals(personalNumber)).findFirst().map(customer -> customer.getBalance(accountNumber)).orElse(0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using `filter` and `findFirst`:

```
return customers.stream()
        .filter(customer -> customer.getPersonalNumber().equals(personalNumber))
        .findFirst()
        .map(customer -> customer.getBalance(accountNumber))
        .orElse(0);
```